# Replicating MouseEvents

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to replicate mouse events inside a applet, such as click based on x/y coords. I currently have a MouseListener implemented which records mouse movements, press, release etc but whenever I try to programmatically replicate mouse events such as Click at x/y the event is never triggered?

Example of a MouseEvent I've tried to replicate click at x/y:

```
applet.getComponent(0).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(applet,
                MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 10,
                MouseEvent.BUTTON1,
               x,y,
                0,
                false));

        applet.getComponent(0).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(applet,
                MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 10,
                MouseEvent.BUTTON1,
               x,y,
                0,
                false));
```

But nothing is registered.. I've searched through multiple stackoverflow posts and just can't seem to find the solution. There's another solution I found and that's using `Java.awt.Robot` but that takes control of system mouse, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Works for me. I used [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#MouseEvent-java.awt.Component-int-long-int-int-int-int-int-int-boolean-int-) constructor of class `MouseEvent` which is not the same the one you used (according to the code you posted in your question). How do you know nothing is registered? I also think that if you post a [mcve] you will improve your chances of getting an answer.